# creating Modal in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I click the Button Modal was popup and automatically hide; How to solve this error in Asp.net

**This is my code**

```
       <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">

                 <!--  Modals-->
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Modals Example
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                          Click  Launch Demo Modal
                        </button>

                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title Here</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                     some text here
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <!-- End Modals-->

                </div>
                </div>
```

help me how to solve this issue

Comment: Is this the only code? Maybe you have something else? I inserted your code into a fiddle and everything works OK! Maybe problem is somewhere else? Check if you load your bootstrap only once. If you have more than one .modal('toggle') call, then first call will open modal and second will close it, maybe thay's the cause, i dunno

Answer (score 0):

Here Bootstrap has write some function you can use these function to open modal

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

If you want to need more information about modal go to below link:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals

Moreover if these solutions do not help you then it may be your document has been reload after open popup that hides automatically.